# Im having one issue editing my image gallery from my news (Im deleting my images from my folder even when I dont want to edit my images gallery)

Tags: php

I have a table "news" and one "gallery".

In my table "gallery" I have a field "news_id", bacause when I insert images in my gallery table, Im inserting images that belong to a news.

I have a file "news-create.php", Where I have a form that asks for a title, content and then I have an input file to select images for gallery(this input file is optional, no required).

Im creating news with sucess, with our without image gallery,  Im creating news correctly.

But now, for editing news in my "news-edit.php", Im having one problem doing my images gallery update.

First, in my "news-index.php" I have a list of all news that I have, and I have a link in each news for when I click in each news I pass to my url id of clicked news:
And now I get this id:

```
$newsId = $_GET['news_id'];
```

Then I have my if to control when my form is submited:

```
if(isset($_POST['sendForm'])){
  $f['title'] = $_POST['title'];
  $f['content'] = $_POST['content'];
}
```

Then I have my update:

```
$updNot = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE news set title=?, content = ? WHERE id_news = ?");
$updNot->bindParam(1,$f['title']);
$updNot->bindParam(2,$f['content']);
$updNot->bindParam(3,$newsId);
$updNot->execute();
```

Then If my update return sucess, I want to verify if my field to select images for gallery was selected to choose images or not.

if it was not selected and my news already have images gallery I want to keep my actual images gallery.

If my news dont have images gallery, and in my edit form I dont select any images for my gallery, I dont want insert any images.

But If I select images for gallery, I want to verify if already exists images in my gallery, if exists I want to remove them for my folder, and then I want to do my upload to my folder and my update in my gallery table with new images.

**The problem is, when I dont select any images Im always entering in my if `if($_FILES['gb']['tmp_name'])`, and then Im removing my images from my folder. And so, when I already have a images gallery in my news and in my edit news page I dont choose any images from gallery, my images are being removed from my folder, and I dont want that.**

**I just want to remove images from my folder, when User in my edit news page select new images from my gallery, and so, first I remove images from my folder relative to my news that is being edited, and then I do my upload and my update in gallery table with new images.**

Somebody there can help me solve this problem? Im here for hours and I dont find any solution for this, bcause when I do my if to verify if user selected new images, but even when user dont select any images Im entering in my if, it seems that I have always images selected even when I dont select it...

So, when my update return sucess I have this code:

```
if($updNot->rowCount() >=1){
 if($_FILES['gb']['tmp_name']){ 
    $readGall = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * from gallery WHERE news_id = ?"); 
    $readGall->bindParam(1, $nesId); 
    $readGall->execute();
    if($readGall->rowCount()>=1){
    while ($resultG = $readGall->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
     if(file_exists($path.$resultGall['img']) && !is_dir($path.$resultGall['img'])){
         unlink($path.$resultGall['img']);
     }
     //here I will do my upload and my update on gallery table when I can fix this problem
    }
  } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You never bothered checking if a file was actually uploaded. You just blindly process the upload. So if nothing was uploaded, or the upload failed, you trash you database with the invalid/incorrect "upload" information.

At bare minimum you should have

```
if($_FILES['gb']['error'] === UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
   ... file was successfully uploaded
}
```

Comment: After all is still not working properly, because now when select new images to my gallery Im not unlink my actual images from my folder..